# Spring should you start a transaction when accessing an object using find?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have a few methods

```
@persistanceContext
EntityManager em;

public Car getCar(int id) {

   em.find(Car.class, id)

}

@Trasnactional

public void saveCar(Car car) {

   em.save(car);
}
```

Should you also start a transaction for methods that are called when you just do a find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use `Read-Only` transaction while fetching the data. It will prevent the data in-consistency while reading and only read those which are committed.

Again its upto best practice, can use without `Transaction` also.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not necessary.Only for saving you need to use @Transactional.

If you use this if any exception occurs in method this will rollback all the previoes operations(i.e insertinsa,deletions)

it will work  based on `do every thing or nothing principle`